# Zonal statistics and list extraction using Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, zonal-statistics, reduceregion

I would like to calculate some zonal statistics for population raster data, over geometries given in a geopandas.GeoDataFrame, and export the results to a Python list.

I wrote some code (see below) that works pretty well for certain GeoDataFrames (first filename in the code below), but not for others (second filename). For the latter, I get the error:

`EEException: Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.`

Apparently, I am using too much memory when using `getInfo()` on a `ee.List`, even if this is composed by a bunch of floats. What I find surprising is that the error occurs only when processing certain dataframes, although the size of the final list is always the same.

The situation does not change if

- Instead of `aggregate_array('sum')` I use

```
z_sum = zonal_statistics.reduceColumns(**{
    'reducer': ee.Reducer.toList(),
    'selectors': ['sum']
    }).get('list')
```

- Instead of `getInfo()` I export the list to Drive.

Can anyone help me understand why this happens?

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import ee

ee.Initialize()

# Set filename
# gdf_filename = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapaction/assessment-resources/main/dataframe_1.geojson'
gdf_filename = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapaction/assessment-resources/main/dataframe_2.geojson'

# Load GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.read_file(gdf_filename)

# Load WorldPop raster and restrict year
pop_collection = ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop")
pop_year = pop_collection.filterMetadata('year', 'equals', 2020)

# Create feature collection out of GeoSeries
polygons_fc = ee.FeatureCollection(gdf.__geo_interface__)

# Retrieve image scale
scale = pop_collection.first().projection().nominalScale().getInfo()

# Merge all images
pop_img = pop_collection.mosaic()

# Calculate zonal statistics
zonal_statistics = pop_img.reduceRegions(
    reducer=ee.Reducer.sum(), 
    collection=polygons_fc, 
    scale=scale
)

# Create list with 'sum' values
z_sum = zonal_statistics.aggregate_array('sum')

# Print list
z_sum.getInfo()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't include large GeoJSON files in your query directly.
You need to upload the GeoJSON as a table, and use it from there.

Or split it into multiple pieces and make multiple queries that are all smaller than the 10MB limit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understand correctly, you are saying that the problem is not in the last line of my code, but rather when I upload the GeoJSON with `polygons_fc = ee.FeatureCollection(gdf.__geo_interface__)`.

Does the 10MB limit apply to the object `gdf.__geo_interface__`? Where do I find these limitations?

Comment: The 10MB limit applies to the final query that you send with the last line, but that line includes everything you've done to produce z_sum object.  (Everything you do in your script just modifies a proxy objects; nothing actually happens until you send that proxy object to the server with, in this case, getInfo()).  So, essentially, yes, it's the FeatureCollection line that's the problem here, where you're including an 18MB GeoJSON file in the query directly.